# manually invoke property injection with AutoFac

Tags: autofac

Suppose all the dependencies have already been registered at the beginning of the program.  At later points in the program how can you use AutoFac to create a new object with a parameterless constructor and inject the registered properties into the object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can register your object in the container with `PropertiesAutowired` then use resolve when you need an instace:

```cs
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
// builder register other dependencies
builder.RegisterType<MyObject>().PropertiesAutowired();

var container = builder.Build();

var myObject = container.Resolve<MyObject>(); //the properties will be filled
```

Or if you don't want to register in the container your can use the `InjectProperties` method on an existing instance:

```cs
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
// builder register other dependencies

var container = builder.Build();

var myObject = new MyObject();
container.InjectProperties(myObject); //the properties will be filled
```